# Correct way to implement an Interface

Tags: c#, interface

Im trying to understand Interfaces and I saw an example in this page but it was not an example of interface in itself.

What I understand about Interfaces:

- Is a contract between the Class that implements (Method, property, event, etc) and the Interface.
- Because in C# and .NET for that matter you can't multi inherit you can use Interfaces where you can use the methods, properties, etc of that Class that you can't inherit.

So **this is a demonstration only** and what I tried:
(In different classes)

```
class Father
{
}

class Mother : IMother
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Im the mother";
    }
}

public interface IMother
{
    string Hello();
}

class Son : Father,IMother
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Son son1 = new Son();
        son1.Hello() // --> Hello does not exist.
    }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `Son` doesn't implement `IMother.Hello`

Comment: Code doesn't compile as is, you must implement Hello() in Son class. How can you have tried this ?

Comment: In general a son is not a father and a mother. This makes the example confusing

Comment: These are some nasty family relationships

Comment: Yes it was only an example, besides the design in which Im not worried right now. thanks tho.

Comment: `Son: Father, IMother` (or `Son: Mother, IFather`) is confusing. Rather make all three implement `IPerson` (or even `ICanSayHello`).

Comment: If you're going to give an example, it should be valid in *every* way except the part you're confused about. So if you're confused because `son1.Hello()` doesn't work, you should make all of the rest of the code compile. An example isn't useful if it's got unrelated errors.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wait Jon, I dont understand you and I want to know what are you thinking about. You mean to take the `son1.Hello()` out of the code so it can compile right? And then ask (out of the code formatting) why I can't call the `Hello()` method in the main entry point, is that what are you telling me? Is that so I will change it then, but first let me know.

Comment: @Nickso: No, I mean to make *everything else* compile apart from `son1.Hello()`. Currently it doesn't compile because `Son` doesn't implement `IMother.Hello()`. If you'd fixed *that* problem when coming up with the example, the problem you were trying to demonstrate (`son1.Hello()` failing to compile) would have gone away.

Comment: @JonSkeet Exactly! and that is because I really did not know that I have to do that. So I wrote "Is a contract between the interface and the class that implements that <Method, property, index>" and I did not implemented the method! really that is because I did not know that. So I wasn't 100% sure what an Interface was, in which case I should have asked that before this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What Am I doing wrong?

You are not implementing `Hello` anywhere in `Son`'s inheritance chain.  If any one of the following was changed you would properly implement the interface:

- `Son` inherits from `Mother` instead of `Father`
- `Father` inherits from `Mother`
- `Father` implements `Hello`
- `Son` implements `Hello`

Interfaces can *not* be used for multiple *inheritance*.  Inheritance is only valid for *implementation* - you can *implement* multiple interfaces but you can't inherit multiple implementations.

If you have multiple classes that you want to re-use the implementations of, then *composition* is typically the best way to do it.  The `Son` class would have references to `Father` and `Mother` objects and either expose them through properties or create pass-through properties and methods to get to the underlying implementations.

Comment: I understand now, this would make more sense if Instead of having "Father" "Mother" I have "Grandfather", "Father" and "Son" where Son and Father inherits from Grandfather and Father have a Method that the Son can use too. so in that case I use an Interface, I was seeing the "Pyramid" of inheritance backwards. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

We use Interfaces to work with abstraction rather than concrete implementation, Why? simple answer it makes testing easy to replace our classes with fake ones, and it create modular applications (OOP)

To fix you code you have to change this line to go the interface variable instead of the class:

```
 IMother son1 = new Son();
 son1.Hello() // --> Now exists.
```

Your code would not work anyways until you implement the interface method inside Son class

```
class Son : Father, IMother
    {
        public string Hello()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to implement the interface method in Son, and you want to access the method in Mother Class, then you have to inherit Mother instead of Father class in Son class.

Comment: What do you mean with "We use Interfaces to work with abstraction rather than concrete implementation"? 

Could you give me an example?

Comment: @DStanley I mentioned that, and I showed how to implement the Hello method.

Comment: @Nickso Example is IMother myClassVar = new Son(); then on the second line you can say myClassVar = new Mother(); you were able to switch implementation using for classes implement the same interface

Comment: Ah that is really cool, so my instance of class can change to another. Do I need an Interface to do this?

Comment: No, the OP doesn't "have to change this line to go to the interface variable instead of the class" - not unless `IMother` is implemented explicitly in `Son`.